# How can I change the InkToolbarStencilButton ruler Length?

Tags: c#, uwp

I want to change the InkToolbarStencilButton's ruler length from code behind. using C#. Possibly on object instantiation.

Comment: I tried 
`InkToolbar.Children.Add(new InkToolbarStencilButton { Margin = new Thickness(10, 0, 10, 10), Ruler = { Length = 200}});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify the style of `Ruler` directly, but the minimum length of `Ruler` is 300.

If your InkCanvas name is `inkCanvas`:

```cs
var ruler = new InkPresenterRuler(inkCanvas.InkPresenter);
ruler.Length = 300;
```

Best regards.